# Сохранение страниц в web.archive.org

Tags: post, get

Программа по списку сохраняет страницы сайта cian.ru на ресурсе `web.archive.org` путем выполнения `GET` запроса:

```
http://web.archive.org/save/ссылка_на_сохраняемую_страницу
```

После n-ой страницы `cian.ru` предлагает ввести рекапчу.
Капчу можно разгадать через сервис антикапчи.
На `cian.ru` ответ на капчу нужно отправить `POST` запросом:

```
https://www.cian.ru/captcha/?redirect_url=https://www.cian.ru/
g-recaptcha-response=[расшифровка капчи]&redirect_url=https://www.cian.ru/
```

Вопрос в том как отправить расшифровку капчи на `cian.ru` через `web.archive.org`, чтобы программа могла дальше продолжить сохранение страниц?

Спасибо!

Comment: Немного дополню вопрос:
"Руками" это сделать не получается, т.е. при появлении капчи cian возвращает HTTP 302...  и web.archive.org переходит с требуемой страницы на страницу с капчей вот такого вида
https://www.cian.ru/captcha/?redirect_url=https://www.cian.ru/
но руками вести эту капчу когда она открывается через web.archive.org не получается т.к. она в этом случае отображается не корректно, вот так:
http://web.archive.org/save/https://www.cian.ru/captcha/?redirect_url=https://www.cian.ru/

поймать момент и отгадать капчу не проблема.

Comment: Вопрос в том как отправить разгаданную капчу в cian.ru через web.archive.org?Проблема в том что web.archive.org работает с сохраняемыми сайтами через GET запросы а капча отправляется на cian.ru POST запросом.
Т.е. возможно есть способ искуственно передать POST запрос в GET запросе т.е. так чтобы cian.ru "поверил" что web.archive.org разгадал капчу